# Mongodb, mongoose - Sorting by _id and date using aggregate and group

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to sort by the `task._id` & `date` in desc order. I am able to sort by `task._id` but sortibg by`date` doesnt work, I tried changing the order in aggregate still no luck. I get the response but just the order by usertasks were added in collection and not by the `usertask.date`

1. User(name, address, etc)
2. Task(name, icon, assignee)
3. UserTask(User.ObjectId, Task.ObjectId, date)

**User Collection:**

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "Bill",
            "phone": "345"
        },
        {
            "name": "Steve",
            "phone": "123"
        },
        {
            "name": "Elon",
            "phone": "567"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Task collection:**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "name": "Run 100m",
            "icon": "run",
            "assignee": "Elon"
        },
        {
            "name": "Walk 1 hour",
            "icon": "walk",
            "assignee": "Bill"
        },
        {
            "name": "Jog 30 minutes",
            "icon": "jog",
            "assignee": "Steve"
        }
    ]
}
```

**UserTasks:**

```
    {
        "_id": "5e72fec..",
        "user": "5e72fa4..",
        "task": "5e72fbac..",
        "date": "2020-03-03T05:10:10.000Z",
        "createdAt": "2020-03-19T05:10:37.027Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-03-19T05:10:37.027Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e72fed3..",
        "user": "5e72fa4e..",
        "task": "5e72fbac..",
        "date": "2020-03-12T05:10:10.000Z",
        "createdAt": "2020-03-19T05:10:43.296Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-03-19T05:10:43.296Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e72fed6..",
        "user": "5e72fa..",
        "task": "5e72fb..",
        "date": "2020-03-15T05:10:10.000Z",
        "createdAt": "2020-03-19T05:10:46.057Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-03-19T05:10:46.057Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e72feda...",
        "user": "5e72fa4..",
        "task": "5e72fb..",
        "date": "2020-03-07T05:10:10.000Z",
        "createdAt": "2020-03-19T05:10:50.785Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-03-19T05:10:50.785Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

**This is the Aggregate that needs changing**

```
    UserTask.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "tasks",
            localField: "task",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "matchedTask"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$matchedTask"
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "user",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "matchedUser"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$matchedUser"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$matchedTask._id",
            name: {$first: "$matchedTask.name"},
            icon: {$first: "$matchedTask.icon"},
            assignee: { $first: "$matchedTask.assignee" },
            userdata: {
                $push: {
                    name: "$matchedUser.name",
                    date: "$date"
                }
            }

        }
    },
    {
      $sort: { _id: 1, "userdata.date": -1 }
    }
  ])

.exec()
.then(doc => res.status(200).json(doc))
.catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
```

**The response is shown below, please note the usertask.date. it is NOT sorted**

```
{
        "_id": "5e...",
        "name": "Run 100m",
        "icon": "run",
        "assignee": "Elon",
        "userdata": [
               {
                "name": "Elon",
                "date": "2020-03-21T20:02:38.143Z"
            },
            {
                "name": "Bill",
                "date": "2020-03-11T20:02:38.000Z"
            },
            {
                "name": "Steve",
                "date": "2020-03-19T20:02:38.000Z"
            }
        ]
    }
```

***As you can see the it is not sorted by date - desc order. The result should be like shown below***

```
"userdata": [
               {
                "name": "Elon",
                "date": "2020-03-21T20:02:38.143Z"
            },
            {
                "name": "Steve",
                "date": "2020-03-19T20:02:38.000Z"
            },
            {
                "name": "Bill",
                "date": "2020-03-11T20:02:38.000Z"
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

$sort will use the last object which comes out from the aggregate pipe and theres no field "date" in this object:

```
 {
        $group: {
            _id: "$matchedTask._id",
            name: {$first: "$matchedTask.name"},
            icon: {$first: "$matchedTask.icon"},
            assignee: { $first: "$matchedTask.assignee" },
            userdata: {
                $push: {
                    name: "$matchedUser.name",
                    execDate: "$date"
                }
            }

        }
    },
```

your group has to returned a field named date in order to be able to sort it

```
{
   $group: {
      _id: "$matchedTask._id",
      name: ....,
      date: ....
   }
}
{ $sort: {date: -1}}
```

if the value you want to sort is indide another object you must specify it on sort:

```
{$sort: {"userdata.date": -1}}
```

Comment: see edit, if you want to sort with the field named "date" it must be present in the group (in the keys)

Comment: I changed the key from execDate to date, still same results, it is not sorting the date (see the edited question)

Comment: see edit, your "main key" here is not date, its userdata, so either you put "date" in the main group object, either you sort by specifing the path of your date "userdata.date",

Comment: Still same result after changing this, please check the updated question, I have provided results aswell

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, had to use sort **two times**, now I am able to get the result as I want

**Solution provided below**

```
UserTask.aggregate([
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "tasks",
            localField: "task",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "matchedTask"
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$matchedTask"
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "user",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "matchedUser"
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$matchedUser"
        },
        {
          $sort: { date: -1 }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$matchedTask._id",
            name: { $first: "$matchedTask.name" },
            icon: { $first: "$matchedTask.icon" },
            assignee: { $first: "$matchedTask.assignee" },
            userdata: {
              $push: {
                name: "$matchedUser.name",
                execDate: "$date"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: { _id: 1 }
        }
      ])
        .exec()
        .then(doc => res.status(200).json(doc))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
```